# How I can get real time output of a process from the terminal while the process is running in c++?

Tags: c++, bash

I am working on something where I need to execute a bash command which will initiate a process and this process really takes a long time to execute. The running process continuously print something on the terminal.  Without completion of the process I cannot get that output. I am doing this in cpp. Is there anyway to get the output from the process in real time without the completion of that process?

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot get that output"?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [tee](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html) to write the output to a file or use a pipe `|` to send the output to another process.

```
$ myprog | tee outputfile.txt
```

or

```
$ myprog | otherpeog
```

The pipe `|` sends the output from the `myprog` to another program.